# Why does console.log() not show inherited properties from Object.create?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am running into a hangup while trying to leverage `Object.defineProperty()` on a base object. I want to inherit properties from that object, using `Object.create()`, and then define more properties in the derived object (which may be inherited from there). I should note that I am targetting this at node.js.

Here's an example:

```
var Base = {};

Object.defineProperty(Base, 'prop1', {
    enumerable:true,
    get:function(){ return 'prop1 value';}
});

Object.defineProperty(Base, 'prop2', {
    enumerable:true,
    value : 'prop 2 value'
});

Object.defineProperty(Base, 'create', {
    value:function(){
        return Object.create(Base);
    }
});

console.log(Base);

var derived = Base.create();

Object.defineProperty(derived, 'prop3', {
    enumerable:true,
    value:'prop 3 value'
});

console.log(derived);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
{ prop1: [Getter], prop2: 'prop 2 value' }
{ prop3: 'prop 3 value' }
```

I thought that console.log() would enumerate the inherited properties, as well as the property `prop3` that I defined on the derived object. It would seem that it does not look up the prototype hierarchy for properties defined in this way. Is that correct?

I looked at overriding the `toString()` method for my object, but it seems that console.log() does not call that.

1. How can I get all properties logged without having to enumerate through them?
2. Is this a valid way to implement inheritance?

EDIT:

1. Is there another function in node.js' libraries that would do the job and log the inherited properties?

Comment: For the lazy: http://jsfiddle.net/aDrjA/1/

Comment: For starters, `console`'s implementation is browser-specific. You really can't rely on it to behave the same way, browser to browser, as each vendor is doing something totally different with the non-standard. When you `console.log(object);` in Chrome dev-tools, you get an expandable node-tree, which has all of the owned methods and properties, and also has the `proto` chain, which has the full inheritance stack... Expecting this in every browser is not going to happen -- programs in some browsers (WP7 IE9) will crash if they even see `window.console`, as they don't even have implementations.

Comment: ***"I should note that I am targetting this at node.js."***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug *does* log the inherited properties:

[image]

while Chrome gives you a tree-view which includes the inherited properties:

[image]

Comment: @dwerner Chrome provides a tree-view. `console.log` is implementation-specific. It seems that Node.js decided to log only own properties. Of course, that doesn't mean that the object doesn't inherit the other two properties.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `console.dir()` where available

```
console.dir(derived)
```

and it'll show the inherited properties of your object on the `__proto__` object

Edit : doesnt seem to show up on node though

Comment: It's also good to know about console.dir() thanks. I'm just not sure I want to rely on `__proto__`.