# Why Object.create does not work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In developer console (Mozilla, Chrome, nvm) this code work as expected:

```
var proto = {x: 3};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
```

So `obj` will be `{x: 3}`

But in node.js i get `{}`
Why?

Comment: I _guess_ it's because the node console doesn't show inherited properties? How are you logging `obj`? `obj.x` is almost definitiely `3`.

Comment: Closely related: [Why does console.log() not show inherited properties from Object.create?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300863/why-does-console-log-not-show-inherited-properties-from-object-create) (though the answers there aren't very practically helpful) (@JanDvorak)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working all right. However, the object `{x:3}` is the *prototype* `obj`. When Node prints out the object, it only prints its own properties. `x` is a prototype property. Try it!

```js
var proto = {x: 3};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
alert(obj.x) // 3
```

(Yes, i know this is a browser, but it's the same JavaScript. :))

Read more: [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: "When Node prints out the object, it only prints its own properties" - do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @JanDvorak I tried to explain it with some doc reference. Please check that.

Answer (score 7):

In Node.js, when you use `console.log` to print something, it uses `util.inspect` to get the string representation of the object. Quoting from [`console.log` doc](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data),

> If formatting elements are not found in the first string then `util.inspect` is used on each argument.

When we check the [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) we understand that, unless it is called with `showHidden` property set to `true`, it will not include the *object's non-enumerable properties*.

But wait, non-enumerable properties are entirely different from properties inherited via prototype chain. So, even `util.inspect` cannot see them. Then how do we get to see the inherited properties?

The only way to get the objects inherited via prototype chain is by using a `for..in` loop. Quoting from [`for..in`'s MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description),

> The loop will iterate over all *enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype* (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override prototypes' properties).

You can confirm that like this

```
var proto = {
    x: 3
};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key);
}
// x
```

Since `console.log` is not part of the ECMA Standard specification, various implementations can implement it as they like. So, the browsers would be internally using the `for..in` loop to gather all the inherited properties whereas node guys decided not to do so.