# Why does node.js don't show a non empty obejct's content?

Tags: node.js

I have this code as example:

```js
const wolf = {
    type: 'canine',
}

const pug = Object.create(wolf, {
    size: { value: 's' }
});

console.log(pug.hasOwnProperty('size')); // true
```

Chrome output:

```
console.log(pug); // {size: 's'}
```

NodeJS 19.0.0 output:

```
console.log(pug); // {}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159240/why-object-create-does-not-work-in-node-js

Comment: But I'm setting `size` property for `pug`. `pug` owns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#parameters) properties are shown when an object is output to the console:

```
> Object.create(wolf, {size: {value: "s", enumerable: true}})
{ size: 's' }
> Object.create(wolf, {size: {value: "s"}})
{}
```