# Object doesn't inherit properties and values

Tags: javascript

I've defined an object and when I instantiate it the instance doesn't contain the properties and values of the parent.

```
const myObject = {
    myNumbers: [7,32,51,2,0,9],
    myName: "John",
    myLastName: undefined,
    age: 26
};

const objectInstance = Object.create(myObject);

console.log(myObject);          //{myNumbers: Array(6), myName: "John", myLastName: undefined, age: 26}
console.log(objectInstance);    //{}
```

objectInstance logs an empty object. I was expecting to see all of the properties and values shown in the log window. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It’s normal for `console.log` to only show a subset of _own_ enumberable properties.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+logging+"object.create") of [Why does console.log() not show inherited properties from Object.create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13300863/4642212).

Comment: What developer tools are you using? In Firefox, you can simply click the arrow to expand the Object and it says `<prototype>: Object { myNumbers: (6) […], myName: "John", age: 26, … }`. Chrome shows a `__proto__` which further expands to a multi-line list of the inherited properties.

Comment: I'm using VS Code as editor (with LiveServer plugin) and Firefox 83.0 as the browser. I can see the prototype values I assumed the object was blank given it being shown as {} rather than having the inherited properties shown else where.

Answer (score 0):

When you `console.log` an object, it only shows the own properties of the object. However, if you want to see the inherited properties, you can unfold the `__proto__` property in the console.

Try logging:

```js
console.log(myObject);                               // {myNumbers: Array(6), myName: "John", myLastName: undefined, age: 26}
console.log(objectInstance);                         // {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(objectInstance));  // {myNumbers: Array(6), myName: "John", myLastName: undefined, age: 26}
```

Comment: [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is deprecated. The modern replacement is [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf). `console.dir` is a better alternative. As currently implemented in major browsers, `console.log`, more specifically, shows a subset of own enumerable properties.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer with `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `__proto__`